# Checking if a variable is greater than zero

Tags: php, if-statement

I am just about to complete my workshop invoicing system but am stumped with the payment module. It basically lists the amount of the invoice, any payments made and gives a balance. The bottom of the form has a html input table to enter an amount to be paid against the said invoice, once the submit button pressed. It writes this to the database, reloads the top of the page and displays the new balances. When the amount outstanding reaches zero, the bottom of the page should read "No payment required" instead of the HTML form. My code to do this is:

**PHP**

```
$balbf =  $invtotal1-$payment;
$balance = number_format((float)$balbf, 2, '.', '');

if ($balance <= 0.00) {
    $color = 'red';
} else {
    $color = 'black';
}

$bal = ($currency."". number_format((float)$balance, 2, '.', ''));
//MAKE PAYMENT
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{ 
    $amnt = $_GET['amount'];
    $amount = number_format((float)$amnt, 2, '.', '');
    $type = $_GET['type'];

    if ($amount >=0.01){
        $pay = "INSERT INTO generalledger (date, account_code, amount, description, supplier_invoice, user_input) VALUES ('$inputdate','1060','$amount','$type payment','INV     $inv','$user')";

        $payinv=mysql_query($pay);
    }

    //REFRESH TOP WINDOW
    echo "<body onload=parent.payment.window.location.reload()>";
    //CHECK IF BALANCE OUTSTANDING
    if ($balance <= 0.00){
        echo "No payment due.";
        exit();
    }else{
```

===> here goes the html form code

It does not work though. If I refresh the page once it reaches zero, it does as it should. Am I missing something? The page is made of two pages in a frame (I know, don't hate me for using frames). I know also that using `mysql_query` is deprecated but its the only format I know.  I can post the whole code or pm if required. Thanks to all for your help....again.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon after if-statement on line 7? `if(isset($_GET['submit']));`

Comment: To be completely honest, I asked for help on this and got some code of Google. If I don't have it, the page does not load. Is it not meant to be there? My apologies for being a bit daft.

Comment: Have you supressed any errors? Since that should give one

Comment: I am using EasyPHP out of the box. I have not suppressed any error that I know of. I tried now removing the semicolon and the page loads blank.

Comment: Your code includes a SQL injection: ``$_GET['type']`` is passed to the query without validating it. Please hire someone that knows how to code securely or get a good programming book. The code posted above does not make many sense and I do not think you coded what you actually wanted to archive.